# Symfony2 Custom Voter Role Hierarchy

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to create a custom voter to check access on entities for specific actions. So the logic for that is working fine. But then I have some actions that are allowed if the user is either the "owner" of that entity, or they are an admin.

However, I can't just check the ROLE of the user because I'm looking at the role hierarchy. The example in the docs for this just uses `in_array`, but that won't work (http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/security.html)

My voter is like this (shortened for clarity). I've tried injecting the security context (or specifically AuthorizationCheckerInterface in 2.6), but that has a circular dependency since this is a voter.

```
<?php
// ...
class ApplicationVoter extends AbstractVoter
{
    const VIEW = 'view';

    /**
     * @var AuthorizationCheckerInterface 
     */
    private $security;

    /*public function __construct(AuthorizationCheckerInterface $security)
    {
        $this->security = $security;
    }*/

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function getSupportedAttributes()
    {
        return array(
            self::VIEW
        );
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function getSupportedClasses()
    {
        return array('Study\MainBundle\Entity\Application');
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function isGranted($attribute, $application, $user = null)
    {
        if (!$user instanceof UserInterface) {
            return false;
        }

        if ($attribute === self::VIEW) {
            return $this->canView($application, $user);
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Can view own application if not deleted
     * Admin can view if submitted
     * 
     * @param \Study\MainBundle\Entity\Application $application
     * @param \Study\MainBundle\Entity\User $user
     * 
     * @return boolean
     */
    protected function canView(Application $application, User $user)
    {
        return ($application->isOwner($user) && !$application->isDeleted())
            || (!$application->isHiddenToAdmin() && $this->security->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN_RO'));
    }
}
```

I'd like to just use the built-in RoleHiearchyVoter here, but it's a non-public service.
Is there some solution for this? I'd like to avoid duplicating framework code or making my roles more complicated than just strings if possible.

**EDIT:** Injecting the whole container works, but isn't my ideal solution. Is that the only way I can access the built-in hierarchy from a voter?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a service called security.role_hierarchy which has the info you need.  It's basically how the security context checks for roles. Need a few lines of wrapper code but it's not too bad.

```
# Need this because the service is not public
# http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/advanced.html
cerad_core__role_hierarchy:
    alias: security.role_hierarchy

cerad_game__game_official__voter:
    class:  Cerad\Bundle\GameBundle\Action\GameOfficial\GameOfficialVoter
    public: false
    arguments:
      - '@cerad_core__role_hierarchy'
    tags:
       - { name: security.voter }
```

The voter class:

```
class GameOfficialVoter implements VoterInterface
{    
    public function __construct($roleHierarchy)
    {  
        $this->roleHierarchy = $roleHierarchy;
    }

    protected function hasRole($token,$targetRole)
    {
        $reachableRoles = $this->roleHierarchy->getReachableRoles($token->getRoles());
        foreach($reachableRoles as $role)
        {
            if ($role->getRole() == $targetRole) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    protected function canViewOfficialName($official,$token)
    {    
         // Pending is the only one protected against for now
         if ($official->getAssignState() != 'Pending') return $this->accessGranted;

         // Assignors can always see
         if ($this->hasRole($token,'ROLE_ASSIGNOR')) return $this->accessGranted;

         return $this->accessDenied;
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess I was just being dumb and assumed `public="false"` on those services meant I couldn't inject them. I don't know why I didn't try this.

Comment: @Matt - I was wondering why I had an alias in my code.  It's been awhile since I looked at it.  You cannot get to the role hierarchy servicewithout first creating an alias.  My answer has been updated.  The dangers of editing after copying. http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/advanced.html

Comment: it looks like when the service is not public, you can inject it in your services.yml/xml configuration, but you cannot get it from the container directly. The alias allows you to get it directly from the container (`$container->get(...)`). I did not need to use an alias to inject the service through the configuration. Thanks!